# Focus on a particular part of a text upon making a new Activity

Tags: java, android, textview

How do I focus on a particular part of a text upon making a new Activity in Android?

I have a long text appear on a new Activity upon clicking a button on a previous Activity. How do I start the screen from the second paragraph, third sentence of the third paragraph, so on? Thank you. :)

Like thus:

- Click 'Read All' button from previous Activity -> Start from first paragraph
- Click 'Section 1' button from previous Activity -> Start from second paragraph, but can still be scrolled upward to show first paragraph.

I hope someone gets what I'm saying! I don't exactly know how to search my problem because I cannot phrase it properly. Sorry if this was already asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Requirement** Every paragraph is an `ListView` item.

Pass the desired paragraph identifier with an `Intent` to the `Activity`. Read the identifier (and resolve it if required) and scroll to the according item with `AbsListView#smoothScrollToPosition(int)`.

I have not tested it, but it could be possible that `AdapterView#setSelection(int)` jumps to the item immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there can be couple of ways to do it, as far as I am getting it -:

1) You can place your TextView inside ScrollView and then you can move the scroll to the middle(or what ever position you want to move) instead of starting.

2) You can make different variables which will contain partial and full text. And then on actions of your buttons you can assign those texts to respective TextViews.

**For example**, Your complete paragraph text is " Focus on a particular part of TextView, such that user can only see a part of it".

Now at first you only want to display a part of it. Let it be "Focus on a particular part of TextView".

Now you can save these two texts in two different variables like -:

```
String completeText = " Focus on a particular part of TextView, such that user can only see a part of it";
String partialText = " Focus on a particular part of TextView";
```

Now you can set the text of the TextView from 'partialText' variable and when user clicks 'Read more' button you can set its text from variable 'completeText'

Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the second solution? Thank you. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks! That's not what I'm looking, however. :(

The text is already complete, however, when the user clicks a button from the previous Activity, the screen focuses on the second line rather than the first... I know it's hard to phrase, so I'm sorry if this sounds vague. :(